# Error using Max_Element with String Vector

Tags: c++11, max

I'm implementing an algorithm to return a vector string array with only the largest elements in the vector string array of entrance:

```
vector<string> solution(vector<string> inputArray) {
vector<string> s;
auto m = *max_element(inputArray.begin(),inputArray.end());
 
for(int i=0;i<inputArray.size();i++){
    if(inputArray[i].size() == m.size())
    {
        s.push_back(inputArray[i]);
    }
}


return s;
```

It works for every test case except in the case the entry string vector is {"enyky", "benyky","yely","varennyky"}. 'm' should return a pointer to "varennyky", but it returns a pointer to "yely" instead.

I digged in to the documentation for max_element, but cant find what I'm doing wrong. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is comparing the strings lexicographically, which is the default comparison in case of strings.

To illustrate, consider the following example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Print a vector of strings
void print_vec(std::vector<std::string> vec)
{
    for (const auto& el : vec) {
        std::cout << el << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// Compares strings by length
bool less_length(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    return s1.length() < s2.length();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> test_0 = {"enyky", "benyky","yely","varennyky"};

    // Default sort and max element
    std::sort(test_0.begin(), test_0.end());
    print_vec(test_0);

    const auto largest_0 = *std::max_element(test_0.begin(), test_0.end());
    std::cout << "Largest member (lexicographically): " << largest_0 << '\n' << std::endl;

    // Sort and max element by string size
    std::sort(test_0.begin(), test_0.end(), less_length);
    print_vec(test_0);

    const auto largest_1 = *std::max_element(test_0.begin(), test_0.end(), less_length);
    std::cout << "Largest member (by string length): " << largest_1 << std::endl;

}
```

The first part of the program runs what you are doing in your function: it finds the maximum element based on lexicographic ordering. According to that ordering, the largest string is `yely`, you can see that by the output from `sort`.

The second part uses a custom comparison function, borrowed directly from [this book](http://www.cppstdlib.com/). It uses string length to determine the order in the `max_element` call and the result is what you were looking for. Again, the sorted vector is also printed for clarity.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! If you don't mind, can you elaborate on how you evoqued the function "less length" without passing the string pointers to it? Thank you!

Comment: Gladly! First, these are references not pointers. Have you read about them? `less_length` is internally called by `max_length` (and `sort`). They both expect a comparison function (lambda, ordinary function like here, function object) with a signature `bool (const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b)` like shown [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) for `max_elem`. `a` and `b` are two elements of the sequence. So the code has this kind of function, pass esit as an argument to `max_element`, and then `max_element` calls it for various  strings, members of the vector.